# Conditional indexing of MatLab structure array by function output

Tags: matlab

I am currently organizing heterogeneous data in structure arrays in MatLab, e.g.,

```
patient.name = 'John Doe';
patient.billing = 127;
patient.test = [79 75 73 180 178 177.5; 220 210 205 79 75 73; 180 178 177.5 20 210 205;];

patient(2).name = 'Ann Lane';
patient(2).billing = 28.50;
patient(2).test = [68 70 68; 118 118 119; 172 170 169; 220 210 205];
```

Let's assume I want to do some more advanced indexing, I want to look at the size of the test field of each patient. These fields all have heterogeneous sizes, which is why I want to use a different struct for each patient.

I want to do something along the lines of this:

```
%This does not work
disp(patient([size(patient.test,1)]>3))
```

For example, check whether the array of patient.test has more than 3 rows and use the resulting boolean array to index the entire structure array. I assume my syntax is simply wrong, but I have not found examples on how to do it properly. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patient.test` will give a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of the field's contents. You can collect that list into a cell array and use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply the `size` function to the contents of each cell:

```
>> sz = cellfun(@size, {patient.test}, 'UniformOutput', false);
>> celldisp(sz)
sz{1} =
     3     6
sz{2} =
     4     3
```

If you only want to display the sizes, you can use `cellfun` to apply an [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) that does that:

```
>> cellfun(@(c) disp(size(c)), {patient.test})
     3     6
     4     3
```

To obtain an index based on the size of the field:

```
>> ind = cellfun(@(c) size(c,1)>3, {patient.test})
ind =
  1×2 logical array
   0   1
```

and then

```
patient_selected = patient(ind);
```

or, if you prefer it in a single line,

```
patient_selected = patient(cellfun(@(c) size(c,1)>3, {patient.test}));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution, it yields the correct output.I am a bit more used to Python syntax where you can write all of this in basically one line - is it also possible in single line, adding onto ```cellfun(@size, {patient.test}, 'UniformOutput', false)``` , to check for the size of each first dimension (e.g., <4, so patient(1) would fulfill the condition) and also use the resulting boolean array to index the entire structure array?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... can you be more specific? Welcome to the site, BTW!

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer is already included in your edit!

Comment: To clarify anyway for future users: I was referring to the single line expression at the bottom of the accepted answer.